# How can i move these vertices in world space instead of moving in local space?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, indices, vertex

I'm using a **"Dymanic Batch Renderer System"**, and i have an **"Object.cpp"** that has a function, and when it's call **it returns the data it needs for the Batch to render a "Quad" on screen** (also i'm gonna mention that this is on a 3D space so the Z movement, Z scaling and the XY rotation exist).

And for the math calculations i'm using the **GLM library**.

The rendering works fine and the batch too, **the problem is the movement**. The rotation actually works the way i want it to work, but the movement is what i'm not satisfied because it moves in the **"Local Space"** of the object. Meaning that, for example, **if i rotate an object inside a batch 90° on the Y Axis, the X movement becomes Z movement, and Z movement becomes X movement**.

I've been trying to look for an answer and i couldn't find anything. I think the problem probably is from the **"rotationMatrix"** that allows the object to rotate correctly, but i don't know if there's an extra "function" i have to add to move the object in the "World Space" instead of the "Local Space", and if there is, i don't know what "function" can be.

Now i'm gonna put here the entire code of **"Object.cpp"** so you guys can see how it works.

```
Object::Object(glm::vec3 pos, glm::vec3 rot, glm::vec3 sca, int ObjId)
            : translationMatrix(glm::mat4(0)), rotationMatrix(glm::mat4(0))
        {
            id = ObjId;
            position = pos;
            lastPosition = pos + glm::vec3(1.0f);
            scale = sca;
            rotation = rot;
            lastRotation = rot + glm::vec3(1.0f);
        }
    
        glm::mat4 One(1.0f);
        Vertex* Object::UpdateObject(Vertex* target)
        {
            if (lastPosition != position)
            {
                translationMatrix = glm::translate(glm::identity<glm::mat4>(), -position);
                lastPosition = position;
            }

            if (lastRotation != rotation)
            {
                glm::mat4 rotMatrixTemp(1.0f);
                rotMatrixTemp = glm::rotate(rotMatrixTemp, glm::radians(rotation.x), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
                rotMatrixTemp = glm::rotate(rotMatrixTemp, glm::radians(rotation.y), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
                rotMatrixTemp = glm::rotate(rotMatrixTemp, glm::radians(rotation.z + 180.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

                rotationMatrix = -translationMatrix * rotMatrixTemp * translationMatrix;
                lastRotation = rotation;
            }

            float x = 1.0f, y = 1.0f;
            if (flipX)
                x *= -1;
            if (flipY)
                y *= -1;

            target->position = rotationMatrix * glm::vec4(position.x - 0.5f * scale.x, position.y + 0.5f * scale.y, position.z, 1.0f);
            target->color = glm::vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            target->texcoord = glm::vec2(0.0f, y);
            target++;

            target->position = rotationMatrix * glm::vec4(position.x - 0.5f * scale.x, position.y - 0.5f * scale.y, position.z, 1.0f);
            target->color = glm::vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            target->texcoord = glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
            target++;

            target->position = rotationMatrix * glm::vec4(position.x + 0.5f * scale.x, position.y - 0.5f * scale.y, position.z, 1.0f);
            target->color = glm::vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            target->texcoord = glm::vec2(x, 0.0f);
            target++;

            target->position = rotationMatrix * glm::vec4(position.x + 0.5f * scale.x, position.y + 0.5f * scale.y, position.z, 1.0f);
            target->color = glm::vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            target->texcoord = glm::vec2(x, y);
            target++;

            return target;
        }
```

So, to recap, what i'm trying to accomplish is moving these objects in the **"World Space"** instead of the **"Local Space"** (while also, keeping the rotation system in the "Local Space", if possible. Because otherwise the object's center is always gonna be (0, 0, 0) instead of being its own position).

Answer (score 0):

To position an object in the world with a given orientation, you usually apply the rotation first then the translation, unless you are indeed trying to rotate the objects about the origin after translating it out. So either check that, or make sure you have a good reason to do have the translationMatrix in

```
rotationMatrix = -translationMatrix * rotMatrixTemp * translationMatrix
```

Because it seems like you have translation logic both in and out of the if blocks